# HTTP Response and Connect Timeout

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to provoke a timeout in the jmeter test.
My settings are right now:

- Reponse TimeOut: 3000ms
- Connect TimeOut: 500ms
  [image: Response Timeout]

But i still got requests over 10.000MS
[image: request ok even with timeout]

First: Did i understood it correct, that request timeout is how long the service is allowed to respond?
And connection timeout how long i will wait for a thread.
Else i would get something like 502 bad gateway?

Or am I completly wrong?

[image]

Edit:
Structure in the Gui

And the xml itself

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.4">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Testplan OneHundred" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="ThreadGroup1" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">60</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">60</stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <ConstantThroughputTimer guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="ConstantThroughputTimer" testname="Constant Throughput Timer" enabled="true">
          <intProp name="calcMode">1</intProp>
          <doubleProp>
            <name>throughput</name>
            <value>100.0</value>
            <savedValue>0.0</savedValue>
          </doubleProp>
        </ConstantThroughputTimer>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="GetRequest" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="Variables pré-définies" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">80</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout">500</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout">3000</stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Host</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">fend</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
          <hashTree/>
          <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
            <objProp>
              <name>saveConfig</name>
              <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
                <time>true</time>
                <latency>true</latency>
                <timestamp>true</timestamp>
                <success>true</success>
                <label>true</label>
                <code>true</code>
                <message>true</message>
                <threadName>true</threadName>
                <dataType>true</dataType>
                <encoding>false</encoding>
                <assertions>true</assertions>
                <subresults>true</subresults>
                <responseData>false</responseData>
                <samplerData>false</samplerData>
                <xml>false</xml>
                <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
                <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
                <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
                <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
                <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
                <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
                <bytes>true</bytes>
                <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
                <url>true</url>
                <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
                <idleTime>true</idleTime>
                <connectTime>true</connectTime>
              </value>
            </objProp>
            <stringProp name="filename">/masterdata/results/backend/de/response_one_get.csv</stringProp>
          </ResultCollector>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you properly apply these setting you will get a [SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)

[image]

The functionality is there for years and it used to work so I can think only of one possible scenario:

1. You're using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) for setting these timeouts
2. HTTP Request sampler(s) are not in [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) of the HTTP Request Defaults, make sure to put the element either at same level or a level above

Comment: thank you very much
I think I'm not using any default as it not looks like your gif, but i could be wrong.
I added another picture of the structure and the xml